# An instance of Wallop with this selector already exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i am building a web app (SPA) and i have the following error with wallop library:

Uncaught Error: An instance of Wallop with this selector already exists.
    at new Wallop (app.js:41105:16)
    at ChilquintaMap.onClickPrevPic (app.js:55745:21)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:35852:13)
    at executeDispatch (app.js:34956:22)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (app.js:34976:8)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (app.js:26877:23)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (app.js:26888:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (app.js:54462:10)
    at Object.processEventQueue (app.js:27064:8)

I want to avoid this error but it keeps showing it when i press my button (next of previous) for second time (or 1 time each).

The slider provided by wallop works tho.

My code is:

```
import Wallop from 'Wallop';

..

onClickNextPic(event){

    var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');

    var slider = new Wallop(wallopEl);

    // Go to next slide
    slider.next();
  }

  onClickPrevPic(event){
    var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');

    var slider = new Wallop(wallopEl);


    slider.previous();
  }

..

render(){
  return (
...
<div className="Wallop Wallop--fade">
                    <div className="Wallop-list">
                      {/*<PhotoViewer fotos={this.state.fotografias} dots={this.state.dots}/> */}
                      {this.state.fotografias}
                    </div>
                    <div className="Wallop-pagination">
                      {this.state.dots}
                    </div>
                    <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                      <button className="Wallop-buttonNext" onClick={this.onClickPrevPic.bind(this)} >Previous</button>
                      <button className="Wallop-buttonPrevious" onClick={this.onClickNextPic.bind(this)}>Next</button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
...
);
}
```

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd be interested in seeing all the code you have for your React component.

Comment: Nope, i changed the lib to react-slick

Comment: Darn, thanks for replying though!